# "HostName not verified error message" on SSL connection in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ssl, ssl-certificate

I created `server.crt`, `server.key` and `root.crt` files on Centos 7 and put the same onto the `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\postgresql` folder in windows as i am running the postgresql server on windows. Now on running my applications using SSL, i am getting the error as

> "The host name could not be verified"

Any help please.

Comment: Are you using the JDBC driver on the client side? If not, what else?

Comment: Yes,JDBC driver i am using

Answer (score 39):

I am using JetBrains Data Grip to access Postgres dbs on Heroku, and got the same error in the latest JDBC driver version. That's how I solved it (using answers provided here).

Set the following in the Advanced tab:

**ssl=true**

**sslmode=require**

**sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory**

(I updated `sslmode` value from `verify-ca` to `required` because it works with Heroku Postgres now)

Comment: yes, "sslmode=verify-ca" is important. The official docs on jetbrains.com do not mention it.

Comment: Actually, `sslmode=require` is the way to go if you are using a self-signed certificate on the server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I agree. I checked sslmode=required works with Heroku now. So, I 
think it is better answer to keep it required so that it can cover self-signed certs. Thank you.

Comment: it should be 'require' not 'required' in sslmode. Your picture shows it correctly but your answer has a typo.

Comment: In my case, `sslmode=require` was sufficient.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't care about hostname verification while still wanting to use a certificate, you can use the additional parameter `sslmode=verify-ca` as a connection parameter or as part of the URL to disable hostname verification while retaining certificate verification.

Comment: interesting that this works even though "Use SSL" is unchecked

Answer (score 9):

To use the PostgreSQL JDBC driver without server certificate validation, use

```
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

as connection parameter or as part of the URL as described in [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html#nonvalidating).

With later versions of the JDBC driver, you have to specify

```
sslmode=require
```

because the default value `verify-full` means that the client wants to check the certificate and identity of the server.