# How to solve the error: "Connection could not be allocated because the hostname could not be verified by hostnameverifier"

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-ec2, heroku-postgres, glassfish-4.1

When I try to make some request to my AWS EC2 instance I'm getting the error "Connection could not be allocated because my_dns_of_postgresql_database could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier", what could I do in this case?

I deployed a server in Glassfish 4.1 (a war file) in an EC2 instance of AWS (a standard one t2.micro). This project makes calls to Heroku's database server in postgreSQL (the database is not in the AWS instance). I've tried to change the security group rules to accept the postgreSQL traffic inbound and outbound, but this doesn't works.

When I don't make a request (just typing the dns address, port and war file name application - like:http://ec2-2-81-22-142.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/TamboServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT/) shows the Servlet response, a Hello World; and when I try it in my PC (localhost) I get a succefull response, so I don't think that it's a problem in the server application. Maybe some configuration in Heroku's database or EC2 instance.

Here are some lines of the server.logs file in Glassfish:

```
[2019-04-06T04:03:45.933+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1554523425933] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Info]: 2019-04-06 04:03:45.932--ServerSession(1545400102)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258]]

[2019-04-06T04:03:45.963+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.postgresql.ssl.PGjdbcHostnameVerifier] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1554523425963] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Server name validation failed: hostname ec2-107-22-163-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com does not match common name ip-10-0-63-18.ec2.internal]]

[2019-04-06T04:03:45.963+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [poolmgr.create_resource_error] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1554523425963] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/post-gre-sql_...), (applicationName=TamboServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT) }. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: The hostname ec2-107-22-163-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier.]]
```

I expect to be able to connect the server, running in a EC2 instance, to the Heroku's database (actually, it is allocated in an AWS machine too). If not, should I migrate the database to the EC2 instance? 
Thanks in advance and sorry if I have made some mistakes writting (I'm not a native english speaker)

Comment: Hostnameverifier is called when your application acting as a client tries to make a connection over ssl and the host name doesn't match the one on the certificate presented by the target giving you a chance to override the verification with a custom validation. Meaning your server is trying to access the database over a secure connection but the certificate used on the database side is not valid, and there is no overriding of the defaul hostname validator.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response. Yes, the problem was in the SSL. I just delete the parameter `ssl` URL in my JDBC connection pool and add `sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`, how sugest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151476/hostname-not-verified-error-message-on-ssl-connection-in-postgresql) response. Now the server works fine! But now, without SSL, is unsafe, how can I solve that?

Comment: As long as you are aware of this: "Provide a SSLSocketFactory that allows SSL connections to be made without validating the server's certificate. This is more convenient for some applications, but is less secure as it allows "man in the middle" attacks." https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ssl/NonValidatingFactory.html

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Currentyl I deleted the parameter `ssl` URL in my JDBC connection pool and added `sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` how sugest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151476/hostname-not-verified-error-message-on-ssl-connection-in-postgresql) response. This is a brute-force solution because allows "man in the middle" atacks, making it unsafe, how says the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ssl/NonValidatingFactory.html), but it's okey for what I'm doing.